# Extract data from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, html

My code is about bookStore with list of books.

I need to extract all data(books) from a JSON file and put them in a `cardView`.

My code is working there I did not got any error but the data is not extracting or printing in a web page.

There is an index.html that structured the page and I wrote also `cardView` code in it.

**index.js class**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
    await handleLoadListValues();
});


async function getBooks(searchOptions) {
    let url = '/api/books/';
    if (searchOptions) {
        url = `${url}?search-options=${searchOptions}`;
    }
    const response = await fetch(url);
    return response.json();
}

async function handleLoadListValues(searchOptions) {
   try {
        const books = await getBooks();

        document.querySelector('#books-table').innerHTML =
            `
         <li class="cards__item">
                <div class="card">
                    <img class="card__image" src="https://unsplash.it/800/600?image=82" alt="">
                    <div class="card__content">
                        <div id="book-title" class="card__title">${title}</div>
                        <p id="book-desc" class="card__text">This is the shorthand for flex-grow, flex-shrink and
                        </p>
                        
                          ${books.map(book => bookToHTMLRow(book)).join('')}  
                       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
             
            </li>`;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }


}
function bookToHTMLRow(book) {
return
       `<li id="card-${book.id}">
                <img src=${book.thumbnailUrl}>
                <div >
                        <div${book.title}</div>
                        <p${book.shortDescription}</p>
                </div>
               
            </li>`;
}
```

**JSON file data Example**

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "title": "Unlocking Android",
    "isbn": "1933988673",
    "pageCount": 416,
    "publishedDate": {
      "$date": "2009-04-01T00:00:00.000-0700"
    },
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/AKIAJC5RLADLUMVRPFDQ.book-thumb-images/ableson.jpg",
    "shortDescription": "Unlocking Android: A Developer's Guide provides concise...",
    "longDescription": "Android is an open source mobile phone... ",
    "status": "PUBLISH",
    "authors": [
      "W. Frank Ableson",
      "Charlie Collins",
      "Robi Sen"
    ],
    "categories": [
      "Open Source",
      "Mobile", "java"
    ]
  },
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: `bookToHTMLRow` does not return anything

Comment: @VLAZ yes I corrected  but still not working

Comment: F12 - error here? `<div id="book-title" class="card__title">${title}</div>`

Comment: @mplungjan what's the error ?

Comment: Title undefined

Comment: Open up the network dev tools and make sure you are actually getting a response from the server

Answer (score 0):

json from [mocky io](https://www.mocky.io/) i test with in case not working mock another one with the same `json` and change the `url` :

```
[
  {
    "id": 777,
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://parismatch.be/app/uploads/2018/04/Macaca_nigra_self-portrait_large-e1524567086123-1100x715.jpg",
    "title": "balabla",
    "shortDescription": "jijiji"
  }
]
```

i tried with `fetech` then I changed to `axios`, I corrected some html tags like:

`<div${book.title}</div>`

**To**

```
<div> ${book.title} </div>
```

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async() => {
  await handleLoadListValues();
});


async function getBooks(searchOptions) {
  const books = await axios.get('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5c94e68a3600006c15941d7e')
  return books.data
}


function bookToHTMLRow(book) {

  return `<li id="card-${book.id}">
                <img src=${book.thumbnailUrl}>
                <div>
                        <div> ${book.title} </div>
                        <p> ${book.shortDescription} </p>
                </div>
            </li>`;
}

async function handleLoadListValues(searchOptions) {
  try {
    const books = await getBooks(true);
    document.querySelector('#books-table').innerHTML = `${books.map(book => bookToHTMLRow(book)).join('')}`;
  } catch (e) {
    //console.log(e);
  }


}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="books-table"></div>
```

Comment: yes to display some data in html as i saw in `bookToHTMLRow` function but i mocked the response

Comment: Getting a 403 on the request to mocky.io, so the snippet doesn't work

Comment: i putted t the `json` i tested  with now